# Swift - drawing lines from one point to another

Tags: swift, cgpath

What is the best way to draw lines from one point to another? I want to draw a line that is the most efficient way to the next point.  Should I be using NSBezierPath?

How would I start this or start learning about this?

Comment: Why not simply use `CGContextMoveToPoint`&  `CGContextAddLineToPoint`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I will look into that. I am new to animations and lines.

Comment: It is hard to give you an advice without knowing your intent or at least having some code.

Comment: My intent is to draw a line from one point to the other while going around obstacles. I am working on something that shows a user the best way to go around a certain area.

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian is totally correct on this; don't make it harder than it needs to be.  To add a few more details, the following code draws a box around a window:

```
CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];

NSRect nsBounds = [self bounds];                                                 // Get the bounds
CGRect cgBounds = NSRectToCGRect(nsBounds);                                      // Sets the graphics bounds

// ******************************************** Box the Window in Gray ********************************************

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0,1.0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,0.0, cgBounds.size.height - 1.0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,cgBounds.size.width - 2.0, cgBounds.size.height - 1.0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,cgBounds.size.width - 2.0, 1.0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,0.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```